# SQL SELECT one row per invoice number where there are no success status

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with financial transactions records. It has invoice_number and status columns. There can be more then one row per invoice_number, meaning that there can be unsuccessful transactions.

I need to query last declined transaction if there is no successful one for certain invoice.

```
invoice_number | status
1              | declined
1              | successful
2              | declined
2              | declined
```

In the example above I need to get only the last row.
How SQL query could look like.
Thank you.

Comment: How do you specify "last"?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: by created_at column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to get the *last* transaction.  Here is one approach:

```
select distinct on (invoice_number) t.*
from transactions t
where not exists (select 1
                  from transactions t2
                  where t2.invoice_number = t.invoice_number and
                        t2.status = 'successful'
                 )
order by invoice_number, created_at desc;
```

If you just want the date, you can use aggregation:

```
select t.invoice_number, max(t.created_at)
from transactions t
group by t.invoice_number
having sum( (t.status = 'successful')::int ) = 0;
```

Comment: I think i missed something in my explanation. I need to get all most recent declined transaction if there is no successful one per invoice.

Comment: @IhorOst . . . "I need to query last declined transaction if there is no successful one for certain invoice."  That is what both queries do.

Comment: I got it! The distinction I need is transaction status
select distinct on (status) t.*.